# Calling other funcation on time

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

how do i call function FB after 5 seconds

after calling FA then take 5 seconds to  call FB to run

```
function FA() {
    $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
      //do stuff
    }
    });
}

function FB() {
    $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {
        //do stuff
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: use setTimeout?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: how, can i see some example

Comment: yes @Jhecht i dont want same call to run at same time after executing

Comment: I'm not understanding your use case, which makes it hard for me to recommend fixes. Why do you want to make a delayed daisy chain of two AJAX calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout(function, ms)`:

```js
function FA() {
  console.log("FA called");
  setTimeout(FB, 5000); //5000 milliseconds
}
function FB() {
  console.log("FB called");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="FA()">Start</button>
```